# Why is BOOL turned to int when negated with explicit block return type

Tags: objective-c

Why is a `BOOL`, which is a `typedef signed char`, converted to an `int` when negated?

```
// Doesn't compile.
NSInteger occurrences = [[contactCountries indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return ![obj isEqualIgnoringCase:@"astring"];
}] count];
```

**Error:**

> return type 'int' must match previous return type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') when block literal has unspecified explicit return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the "C" in Objective-C. C99 says this about the `!` operator (emphasize mine):

6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators, paragraph 5:

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. **The result has type int.** The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).

Simply cast it:

```
return (BOOL)![obj isEqualIgnoringCase:@"astring"];
```

Comment: Correct, but the better solution is to specify the block return type explicitly: `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { …` , instead of casting the return value.

Comment: @MartinR: Yeah, that's how I solved it. I was just interested, why this happened.

Comment: @MartinR: Aye, that is indeed nicer.

Comment: @DarkDust, after reading your answer i understand that result of ! will always 0 or 1, m i right ?

Comment: @Jageen: Correct. Same is true of comparison operators `==` and `!=`, so `(1 == 1) + (1 != 2) + !0` yields 3.

Comment: @DarkDust,Sorry to ask you another question, but if i write 
    BOOL bTest = !0;
    NSInteger nTest = !NO; compiler did not show error bTest will get YES and nTest will get 1, so why Leandros getting error in explicit block

Comment: @Jageen, the problem is not the mismatch between `BOOL` and `int`. It's the mismatch between the block types. When a block is defined without an explicit return type, the compiler derives the type by examining the `return` statements in the block and the types of the returned expressions. So, the type of the block in the question is `int (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)` while the `-indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` method requires a block of type `BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)`.